# Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'category' between objects in different contexts

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I have few Swift Data objects, Transaction, Category, Account, and Budget

```
@Model
final class Budget: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: String
    var category: Category?
    var account: Account?
    var budgetAmount: Double
    var duration: String

    init(
        category: Category? = nil,
        account: Account? = nil,
        budgetAmount: Double,
        duration: String
    ) {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
        self.category = category
        self.account = account
        self.budgetAmount = budgetAmount
        self.duration = duration
    }
}
```

In Create Budget screen I am fetching my accounts and categories.
Users selects an account, category and im trying to save a Budget Object to SwiftData, but i am getting this error "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'category' between objects in different contexts"

If I pass nil as Category of the budget, the error will complain about the Account. If I pas nill for both, Account and Category, the object is created.

My save budget function

```
    private func saveBudget() {
        guard let selectedCategory, let amount = Double(amountString) else { return }
        
        let budget = Budget(
            category: selectedCategory,
            account: accounts.first,
            budgetAmount: amount,
            duration: selectedBudgetDuration.rawValue
        )
        modelContext.insert(budget)
    }
```

however if in the same func I try to save a transaction object that also has Account and Category relations, it saves the Transaction normally.

```
    private func saveBudget() {
        guard let selectedCategory, let amount = Double(amountString) else { return }
        
        let transaction = Transaction(
            amount: 234,
            date: .now,
            isExpense: true,
            category: selectedCategory,
            account: accounts.first
        )
//        let budget = Budget(
//            category: selectedCategory,
//            account: accounts.first,
//            budgetAmount: amount,
//            duration: selectedBudgetDuration.rawValue
//        )
        modelContext.insert(transaction)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to change the modelContainer in different ways, but didnt help.

```
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        //.modelContainer(for: [Budget.self, Category.self])
        //.modelContainer(for: Budget.self)
        .modelContainer(for: Category.self)
```

Update:
All the functions happen in the AddBudgetVie, basic setup, I have a textfield for the amount, a picker for the category and a save button that calls create budget.

```
struct AddBudgetView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    @State private var amountString = ""
    @State private var showCategoryPicker = false
    @State private var selectedCategory: Category?

    @State private var isShowingFilter = false
    
    @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Category.name)])
    private var categories: [Category]

    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Account> { $0.isCurrent })
    private var accounts: [Account]
}
```

What I found is if I change my Budget class like this, it works. But my other Classes like Transaction don't have such an Init setup and all work just fine.

```
@Model
final class Budget: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: String
    var category: Category?
    var account: Account?
    var budgetAmount: Double
    var duration: String

    init(
        category: Category? = nil,
        account: Account? = nil,
        budgetAmount: Double,
        duration: String
    ) {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
        self.budgetAmount = budgetAmount
        self.duration = duration
        setCategory(category)
        setAccount(account)
    }
    
    private func setCategory(_ category: Category?) {
        self.category = category
    }
    
    private func setAccount(_ account: Account?) {
        self.account = account
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is saveBudget declared, where does the value for selectedCategory come from, how is modelContext declared? Could you try to post a reproducible example?

Comment: Hey @JoakimDanielson, thanks for your reply, I have added an Update part to my question.

Comment: this is getting even crazier. Without making any other changes, it started working. I have removed the new init version in the Budget and put it back to the original with setting relationship objects in the Init. my model context is set to       .modelContainer(for: [Budget.self, Category.self])

Comment: The code looks fine and if the issue is resolved then please remove the question. Maybe this was just an issue with Xcode's build system and your last change triggered a rebuild of something.

Comment: looks like this is a known issue, I found a similar https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738961 I will keep the question just in case someone else has a similar issue.

Comment: Then post what you did as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, if you change your Init of the model as below, it will work. However, for some unknown reason, it started working with the old code as well without any changes to the Init.

//my WindowGroup

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
}
.modelContainer(for: [Budget.self, Category.self])
```

//and my model

```
@Model
final class Budget: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: String
    var category: Category?
    var account: Account?
    var budgetAmount: Double
    var duration: String

    init(
        category: Category? = nil,
        account: Account? = nil,
        budgetAmount: Double,
        duration: String
    ) {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
        self.budgetAmount = budgetAmount
        self.duration = duration
        setCategory(category)
        setAccount(account)
    }
    
    private func setCategory(_ category: Category?) {
        self.category = category
    }
    
    private func setAccount(_ account: Account?) {
        self.account = account
    }
}
```